# use an env variable as part of the name of a different env variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Assume I have some environment variable named `TMP=VAR` and a second environment variable `VAR_A=RES`.
Is there and way I can access `VAR_A` via the variable `TMP`, i.e., something like: `${${TMP}_A}` in bash?

Thanks!

Comment: Variable indirection is available, but in a large number of cases, you'll be better off with an associative array.

Comment: There is a possibility to use reference variable

Comment: `VAR_A="hello" ; MY_TMP="VAR" ; declare -n ref="${MY_TMP}_A" ; printf "%s\n" "${ref}"`